# 2 functions don't work, they show errors instead if I click on the buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to programming on JS, and I need help.

HTML Code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <center>
    <label style="font-size: 30px;">Cookie Clicker Test</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a onclick="count();" href="#" id="clickbtn">Click Me!</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Clicks: </label>
    <label id="a">0</label>
    <br>
    <label>CPS: </label>
    <label id="b">0</label>
    <br>
    <a onclick="buyAutoClicker();" href="#" id="clickbtn" xml:id="autoclickerbtn">AutoClicker - 100 Cookies</a>
    </center>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS Code

```
<script>
var a = 0;

function count() {
    a += 1;
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = a;
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = a / 10;
}

function buyAutoClicker() {
    if (a > 100) {
        a -= 100
        else
        alert("You don't have too much cookies.");
    }
}

</script>
```

My problem is, if I click a button, it shows an error, saying that "count()" is not defined, and if I try another button, it says "buyAutoClicker()" is not defined, if I remove one function, no errors.

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: count is not defined
onclick

Uncaught ReferenceError: buyAutoClicker is not defined
onclick
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript within the HTML page or as a separate file. If separate file, you need to add the reference of it

Comment: If you are using inline check placement.

Comment: If the JS code is inline, check it for the syntax errors too. If it's coming from an external file, make sure the file is actually loaded. Syntax errors can be seen in the console of the DevTools, and you can check the Network tab to see, whether the JS file is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate issue is that the else statement is incorrectly formatted in your JS code, if you add braces around the else (or remove braces from the if statement completely) it should work:

```js
var a = 0;

function count() {
    a += 1;
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = a;
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = a / 10;
}

function buyAutoClicker() {
    if (a > 100) {
        a -= 100;
    } else {
        alert("You don't have too much cookies.");
    }
}

/* Not using braces after compound statements (e.g. if, else, etc.) shown below is generally 
 * not recommended since doing so can introduce bugs like Apple's #gotofail:
 * https://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/2014/03/apples-gotofail-ssl-security-bug-was-easily-preventable/
 */
function buyAutoClicker2() {
    if (a > 100)
       a -= 100;
    else 
       alert("You don't have too much cookies.");
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <center>
         <label style="font-size: 30px;">Cookie Clicker Test</label>
         <br>
         <br>
         <a onclick="count();" href="#" id="clickbtn">Click Me!</a>
         <br>
         <br>
         <label>Clicks: </label>
         <label id="a">0</label>
         <br>
         <label>CPS: </label>
         <label id="b">0</label>
         <br>
         <a onclick="buyAutoClicker();" href="#" id="clickbtn" xml:id="autoclickerbtn">AutoClicker - 100 Cookies</a>
      </center>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the  tag just below the  tag like

```
<body>
  <script>
  .
  .
  </script>
  .
</body>
```

And also use different id for both button. They are using same id = 'clickbtn'.